# C++ random number generator for a die

Tags: c++

I cannot seem to get the rand() function to work properly.  Here is a sample of my code that asks for the number of sides of the die and then should generate a random number(a roll of the die) based on the number of sides.  I keep getting the same number in the value variable.  What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int numSides;
    int value;
    cout << "Please enter the number of sides of the dice: ";
    cin >> numSides;

    value = rand() % numSides + 1;

    cout << endl << value;


}
```

Comment: You need to seed the RNG, otherwise you get the same random sequence every time you run the program.

Comment: ***I keep getting the same number in the value variable*** That is because you forgot to seed the random number generator 1 time at the beginning of your main().

Comment: You are not initializing the random number generator with a random 'start' value, so it will always produce the same sequence of numbers.

Add #include<time.h>
and at same stage before the call to rand, add the following code
 srand(time(NULL));

Comment: Check out [`rand()` Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful).